# Laravel/Lumen 5.3.3: override env values in migrations

Tags: php, laravel, migration, environment-variables, lumen

In laravel documentations I vividly see:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration
>
> You may also create a .env.testing file. This file will override
> values from the .env file when running PHPUnit tests or executing
> Artisan commands with the --env=testing option.

So I suppose by adding a `.env.migration` file and overriding mysql user credentials, I can run my migrations with another user:

```
php artisan migrate --env=migration
```

Well not only it does not override previously defined values, it does not even add new values to environment! In fact artisan command does not load the file at all. I changed the file name to testing, no avail. I updated my composer, still no result.

I have a simple question. *What is the best way to handle laravel migrations with another database credentials?*

It's also welcomed if I know where is the migration script located in lumen package, so I can start digging into scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed in 5.3.11 with [this PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15629). If you upgrade to at least that version, artisan commands will respect the `--env` setting when loading `.env` files.

If you're using Lumen, you'll need to update your `bootstrap/app.php` file.

Near the top of the file is this block of code:

```
try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}
```

This should be replaced with something like the following:

```
$suffix = '';

if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

    if ($input->hasParameterOption('--env')) {
        $suffix = '.'.$input->getParameterOption('--env');
    }
} elseif (env('APP_ENV')) {
    $suffix = '.'.env('APP_ENV');
}

$env = '.env';
if ($suffix && file_exists(__DIR__.'/../'.$env.$suffix)) {
    $env .= $suffix;
}

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../', $env))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}
```

NB: untested, but the idea should work.

Comment: I guess this is a fix on `Laravel`. I'm using `Lumen`.

Comment: Thanks @patricus, I'll try it soon. I'll let you know about the result.

Comment: I tested the code and updated the answer. It works fine (Y). Feel free if you want to update it again :)

Comment: @HPM Glad it worked out for you. The edit was an interesting idea, but it goes contrary to how Laravel works (which is what most people will be familiar with). The expectation is that you get one env file, there is no cascading effect on env files. But, I'm glad you were able to implement it the way you wanted.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but as I mentioned in question Laravel docs states .env.whatever is supposed to override original values. By the way I think we still need to update the answer, cause at the point we're loading the env, no env var is loaded here: `elseif (env('APP_ENV')) {
    $suffix = '.'.env('APP_ENV');
}` we have to remove this part
Thanks again :)

Comment: @HPM I think the documentation is just poorly worded. The only place in Laravel that the `.env` files are loaded is in [`Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/DetectEnvironment.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.3.28/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/DetectEnvironment.php#L24), and you can see that it will only ever load just one file. So, it isn't actually correct to say "This file will override values from the .env file", it is more correct to say "This file will be used to set environment variables instead of the .env file".

Comment: @HPM Regarding the `elseif()` code you referenced, it is only attempting to set the `$suffix` variable if the `APP_ENV` environment variable is set. If it isn't set, the `$suffix` will remain blank, and then the plain `.env` file will be loaded below.

Comment: Got it, it's possible to set APP_ENV or any other env variable in the command line on the fly (Y)
And also thanks for laravel docs clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I use to update specific .env values at runtime (even if the configuration is cached).  I'll put the security caveat in there, that calls to a method like this should be gaurded tightly and user input should be sanitized properly.

```
private function setEnvironmentValue($environmentName, $configKey, $newValue) {
    file_put_contents(App::environmentFilePath(), str_replace(
        $environmentName . '=' . Config::get($configKey),
        $environmentName . '=' . $newValue,
        file_get_contents(App::environmentFilePath())
    ));

    Config::set($configKey, $newValue);

    // Reload the cached config       
    if (file_exists(App::getCachedConfigPath())) {
        Artisan::call("config:cache");
    }
}
```

An example of it's use would be;

```
$this->setEnvironmentValue('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'app.log_level', 'debug');
```

`$environmentName` is the key in the environment file (example.. APP_LOG_LEVEL)

`$configKey` is the key used to access the configuration at runtime (example.. app.log_level (tinker `config('app.log_level')`).

`$newValue` is of course the new value you wish to persist.

Comment: This code start to override env and config values after they are loaded, but I like to bootstrap my application with the overridden values. Quite often a simple env var effect on how another config var(s) is built up. It's impossible to track how an env var affects the whole application.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
try {
    // < L5.8
    // (\Dotenv\Dotenv(dirname(__DIR__,1), '.env')->overload();
    // >= L5.8
    ( \Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable( dirname(__DIR__,1).'/.env' ) )->load();
} catch ( \Dotenv\Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e ) {
    //
}
```

[read this article](https://medium.com/@sirajul.anik/laravel-lumen-overload-existing-environment-variables-949eaa354a86).

[dotEnv repo](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)